# How do I save Xamarin TimePicker value to database?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, datepicker, timepicker

I'm using SQLite to store data from a Xamarin.Forms app. I want the user to be able to use the DatePicker for a date and the TimePicker for a time and then store it. When I use the following:

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding Date}"
    x:Name="DatePicker"
    Format="D" />
```

It stores the chosen date in the database correctly but when I use:

```
<TimePicker Time="{Binding Time}"
     x:Name="TimePicker"
     Format="T"/>
```

It stores the time as 12:00 AM every time. What am I missing?

Date and Time are both DateTime values in the database.

```
using System;
using SQLite;

namespace Items.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using Items.Models;

namespace Item.Data
{
    public class ItemDatabase
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public ItemDatabase(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<Item>().Wait();
        }

        public Task<List<Item>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            //Get all items.
            return database.Table<Item>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<Item> GetItemAsync(int id)
        {
            // Get a specific item.
            return database.Table<Item>()
                            .Where(i => i.ID == id)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(Item item)
        {
            if (item.ID != 0)
            {
                // Update an existing item.
                return database.UpdateAsync(item);
            }
            else
            {
                // Save a new item.
                return database.InsertAsync(item);
            }
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(Item item)
        {
            // Delete an Item.
            return database.DeleteAsync(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't shown any actual code you are using to store or retrieve the time

Comment: @Jason Now I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it wrong the type of `TimePicker.Time`,  it should be `TimeSpan` not `DateTime` , so the binding is created incorrectly, that is the reason why the value not change when select the time on TimePicker .

Modify your code as below

```
public class Item
    {

        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @ColeX-MSFT ! That did it! When I looked up data types in the SQLite documentation, there was no data type of TimeSpan but it looks like the C# TimeSpan is stored correctly :-)